Databricks Performance Tuning with Joins around 15 tables with around 200 Million Rows
As part of our Databricks notebook, we are trying to run sql joining around 15 Delta Tables with 1 Fact and around 14 Dimension Tables.  The Data coming out of Joins is around 200 Million records.
When we are doing
df = spark.sql('.....')   --> This sql is joins of around 15 Delta Tables
df.count()
It is running for around 5 to 7 hrs and giving error saying:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 1504 ($anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$5 at LexicalThreadLocal.scala:63) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4
We have already run
OPTIMIZE Dim1 ZORDER BY (Dim1SK);
ANALYZE TABLE Dim1  COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR ALL COLUMNS;
Done above for all 15 Delta Tables and ran the sql.
What are the better ways to fix this.
Tried separating into multiple sqls by joining Fact and Dim1, Dim2, Dim3, Dim4 into a DataFrame
Then join this DataFrame with Dim5,6,7,8 and so on.
Even this is taking more time.

Have you done partitions on the join key column?

Try tinkering with your cluster config. Try either increasing the size of the cluster and/or the number of nodes. Depending on your data, one or both should show some performance improvement. Also do a partition with keys which are part of the joins/where clause.

It's pretty difficult to even make guesses without either the sql or query plans.  Can you please add some examples into the question?

A broadcast join, also known as a map-side join, is a join execution strategy that distributes the join operation across cluster nodes.
It is highly efficient for joining a large table (fact table) with relatively small tables (dimension tables).
In this method, the smaller dataset is broadcasted to all executors within the cluster.
Each executor then hashes the broadcasted dataset and performs the join operation with the larger dataset.
I have tried the below approach:
df_joined = df_fact.join(F.broadcast(df_dim1), "id", "left")
                   .join(F.broadcast(df_dim2), "id", "left")
               
               

Results:
id  value   dim1_value  dim2_value
1   100 Dim1_Value1 Dim2_Value1
2   200 Dim1_Value2 null
3   300 null    Dim2_Value2
4   400 null    null

